# Is there support for compression in ReactiveMongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, akka, akka-stream, reactivemongo

I am using [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/) as the connector for an Akka-Http, Akka-Streams project. I am creating the MongoConnection as shown below, but the data in the database is compressed using Snappy. No matter where I look, I can't find any mention of compression support in the ReactiveMongo documentation. When I try to connect to the Mongo database using a URL with the compressors=snappy flag, it returns an exception.

I looked through the source code and indeed it appears to have no mention of compression support at all. At this point I'm willing to accept a hack work around.

Can anyone help me please?

```
MongoConnection.fromString("mongodb://localhost:27017?compressors=snappy").flatMap(uri => driver.connect(uri))
```

Exception:

```
23:09:15.311 [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-6] ERROR akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl - Error during processing of request: 'The connection URI contains unsupported options: compressors'. Completing with 500 Internal Server Error response. To change default exception handling behavior, provide a custom ExceptionHandler.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The connection URI contains unsupported options: compressors
    at reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver.connect(AsyncDriver.scala:227)
    at reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver.connect(AsyncDriver.scala:203)
    at reactivemongo.api.AsyncDriver.connect(AsyncDriver.scala:252)
```

If you need a workable example, you can try this:
(You don't actually need a MongoDB container running locally for the error to be thrown)

```
object ReactiveMongoCompressorIssue extends App {
  import scala.concurrent.Await
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem("ReactiveMongoCompressorIssue")
  implicit val dispatcher: ExecutionContextExecutor   = actorSystem.dispatcher

  final val driver = AsyncDriver()
  val url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/?compressors=snappy"

  val connection = Await.result(MongoConnection.fromString(url).flatMap(uri => driver.connect(uri)), 3.seconds)

  assert(connection.active)
}
```

Comment: No there isn't such option. The compressor option doesn't compress the DB, but the messages over network. DB compression is managed in DB option, not on driver side. Network compression is not planned to be supported soon.

Comment: Which compression do you want, on the network between client and server or for data stored by the server?

Comment: I need Snappy compression support.

Comment: How was the data compressed?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to what @cchantep said about how compression in MongoDB is handled on the server side (see the [MongoDB docs here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/wiredtiger/#compression)) I went back through the ReactiveMongo source code to see if there was a way to either bypass the check or remove the flag from the URL myself and connect without it.

Indeed, I found that there is a boolean flag called `strictMode` which determines whether `ignoredOptions` such as the `compressors` flag should cause an exception to be thrown or not. So now my connection looks like this:

```
MongoConnection.fromString(url).flatMap(uri => driver.connect(uri, None, strictMode = false))
```

The `None` refers to a name of a connection pool, but the other `connect` method I was using before doesn't use one either so this works fine.

Thank you for the help!